# From phone prefixes to regular expressions

Tags: transform

I have a list of phone prefixes (about 50k) and I would like to pass them to regular expressions to reduce the number of lines.

Is there any tool that does it automatically? Does anyone know any script that will do it for me (php, javascript, python, etc), or how can I do that?

To better understood.

I have this..

| Prefix | Country |
| --- | --- |
| 62 | INDONESIA |
| 6221 | INDONESIA (JAKARTA) |
| 6222 | INDONESIA (OTHER CITIES) |
| 62251 | INDONESIA (OTHER CITIES) |
| 6231 | INDONESIA (OTHER CITIES) |
| 62341 | INDONESIA (OTHER CITIES) |
| 62361 | INDONESIA (OTHER CITIES) |
| 62411 | INDONESIA (OTHER CITIES) |
| 6261 | INDONESIA (OTHER CITIES) |
| 62778 | INDONESIA (OTHER CITIES) |
| 628 | INDONESIA MOBILE |
| 6281 | INDONESIA MOBILE |
| 6282 | INDONESIA MOBILE |
| 6283 | INDONESIA MOBILE |
| 6285 | INDONESIA MOBILE |
| 6286 | INDONESIA MOBILE |
| 6287 | INDONESIA MOBILE |
| 6288 | INDONESIA MOBILE |
| 62877 | INDONESIA MOBILE XL |
| 62878 | INDONESIA MOBILE XL |
| 62879 | INDONESIA MOBILE XL |

And I want to reduce it to something like this...

| Prefix | Country |
| --- | --- |
| `^62\[0-9\]+$` | INDONESIA |
| `^6221\[0-9\]+$` | INDONESIA (JAKARTA) |
| `^62(3 | 6)1\[0-9\]+$` | INDONESIA (OTHER CITIES) |
| `^623(4 | 6)1\[0-9\]$` | INDONESIA (OTHER CITIES) |
| `^6222\[0-9\]+$` | INDONESIA (OTHER CITIES) |
| `^662251\[0-9\]+$` | INDONESIA (OTHER CITIES) |
| `^62411\[0-9\]+$` | INDONESIA (OTHER CITIES) |
| `^62778\[0-9\]+$` | INDONESIA (OTHER CITIES) |
| `^628(1|2|3|5|6|7|8)\[0-9\]+$` | INDONESIA MOBILE |
| `^6287(7|8|9)\[0-9\]+$` | INDONESIA MOBILE XL |

Thanks

Comment: What's the end goal here? You want to reduce the number of lines, but to what end? How are these expressions going to be used?

Comment: Hello Robby.
Thanks for your quick response.
The goal is to transform a prefix-destination listing of approximately 50k records to a regular expression-destination for later, be used in a software that, using regular expressions, obtains the destination of millions of phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, what is the end goal yet, but if you are generating the regexp's from the list, why worry about optimizing the length of the regexp and not just letting the regexp-compiler do the optimization. Example in python:

```
prefixes = ["6222", "62251", "6231", "62341", "62361", "62411", "6261"]
regex_as_str = "^("+"|".join(prefixes)+")\d+$" # Creates "^(6222|62251|6231|62341|62361|62411|6261)\d+$"
regex = re.compile(regex_as_str)
```